# How to change background color of ListTile?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am make settings page and want make like iOS settings (grey background and white tile). I am try add Container so can add color to ListTile but always get error.

Anyone know how to add Container here?

```
  body: new SingleChildScrollView(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[

               Column(

                children: <Widget>[

                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    title: Text("Account"),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                  ),
```

Comment: If I did understand, you want something like [that](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_cupertino_settings#-readme-tab-). So I don’t understand If you wanna change tile background or the parent container (column) background.

Answer (score 16):

Just wrap your `ListTile` in a `Container`

2019 answer

```dart
      Container(
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              title: Text("Account"),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            ),
          )
```

Updated answer (after this PR was merged in 2020 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/61347)

```dart
 ListTile(    tileColor: Colors.grey[200],
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              title: Text("Account"),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have try this but is possible to wrap all ListTiles in Container so I no have to repeat wrap for every ListTile? Give error 'children isn't defined' when try use children: <Widget>[ in Container.

Comment: Two options, wrap your column inside a Container with color or  create a StatelessWidget and write your item there ( container -> ListTile)

Comment: Why doesn't the tileColor property of the ListTile set its color?

Comment: 'cause this answer is from 2019 :D

Answer (score 10):

I wrap the `ListTile` with a `Material` widget and set the color. This will preserve the ripple effect of the listTile.

eg.

```
Material(
        color: Colors.grey[300],
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Hello')
              )

    );
```